# Why does setting a Sprite subclass's object's width and height in its contructor make its TextFieldRenderers not show up?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, sprite

Please explain why this will show a label if and only if the width and height are not set:

```
package  
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.text.TextField;

    public class Screen extends Sprite
    {

        public function Screen() 
        {
            super();
            // width = 640;
            // height = 480;

            var lbl:TextField = new TextField();
            lbl.textColor = 0xFFFFFF;
            lbl.text = "This is a disclaimer.";
            addChild(lbl);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading this right, which I think I am, it is coming down to a basic error. You haven't declared the width and height properties ANYWHERE in scope (within the class or the function). So, what's basically happening is that, because of the error, the code is aborting before it gets to defining the TextField.

You appear to be trying to set the Sprite's width and height. To do that, the lines need to be...

```
this.width = 640;
this.height = 480;
```

`this` is a special keyword that points AS3 directly back to the object this relates to directly. Without `this`, AS3 thinks you're just working with some variables, and you haven't declared any such variables in scope.

Frankly, however, I'm surprised you're not getting an error message. What IDE are you using?

Comment: In ActionScript 3, when you don't have local variables with the same names, `this.` is implicit.

Comment: Eh, it has not always been implicit for me. Implicit can be dodgy at times. A good rule of thumb: if you CAN write it out, DO write it out. That said, this may indeed not be the problem, but it is what I spotted.